# How to pass variables to a form before it is processed

Tags: python, django, forms, http-headers, amazon-s3

I have the following template form, containing several variables.

```
<form action="https://me.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="upload-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="videos/{{filename}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{access_key}}"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{policy}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{signature}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="{{content_type}}">
    <input name="file" type="file"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">
</form>
```

However, as soon as the submit button is hit, the form is sent to amazon, and I'm not able to pass it variables. This is what I've been trying to do, unsuccessfully --

```
    if 'upload' in request.POST:
        policy = base64.b64encode(...)
        signature = base64.b64encode(
            hmac.new('secret_key', policy, sha).digest())
        file = request.POST['files']
        filename=file.name
        content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
```

What do I need to do to pass the variables to the form after the POST request but BEFORE amazon processes the form? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your form's action to your django view and in your view you can re-post to `https://me.s3.amazonaws.com/`:

In your template

```
<form action="http://mywebsite/upload" method="post" ...
```

In your view.py:

```
def upload(request):
    # Your treatment here.
    # Post the data to amazon S3.
    urllib2.urlopen("https://me.s3.amazonaws.com/", your_data)
    ...
```

Comment: Great, thank you. And what, exactly is `your_data`, is this a dictionary or how would I pass it? Thank you.

Comment: @David542: yes it's a dictionary that when is passed to urllib2.urlopen it will make a post request, you can check the related [doc][http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the form to POST to one of your own views, then do your post-processing in your view, and then within your view code, issue a POST to Amazon with the correct values using, say, [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or similar.